# Scraping en ids variables

Tags: python, selenium, scraping, id

Hola buenas me encuentro realizando scraping con python en la siguiente pagina web https://stresse.ru/.

A la hora de intentar hacer click en el boton de `Send Layer 4 Attack` con la siguiente orden:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ff557a").click()
```

El programa lanza error de que no puede encontrar el elemento devido a que el ID cada vez que se habre la pagina web en modo incognito cambia el ID del boton.

Por lo que necesito saber si hay alguna forma con selenium o con alguna otra herramienta de scraping de buscar el ID del boton para poder pulsarlo.
Otra posible solucion seria buscar IDS que cumplan con un patron similar al del boton que busco pulsar que por lo que he estado viendo todos los ids empiezan por `"ff"`

Muchas gracias de antemano;

Comment: Me parece a mi o ese enlace se trata de un sitio que ayuda a enviar ataques cibernéticos de forma ilegal?

Comment: Es un ipstresser para estresar una ip

Comment: Mientras estés probando con tu propia IP o de manera local, no hay problema. Saludos.

Comment: Es una opción que el programa eliga entre dos ids dependiendo si la pagina fue abierta en modo incognito o no? Quizá hay una forma de que selenium sepa eso

Comment: No el programa crea un id de forma aleatoria. Lo unico que sigue un patron de que los primeros dos caracteres son siempre `ff`